# Dask - distributed.diskutils Error - Failed to remove TEMP_FILE: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: TEMP_FILE

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

I'm trying to use Dask to parallelize some data processing. However, my workers fail when they try to delete a file that seems to be created in the DASK_TEMPORARY_DIRECTORY I specified. Basically, the error is as follows:

```
distributed.diskutils - ERROR - Failed to remove '/path_to_dask_temporary_directory/scheduler-mwho36kr' (failed in <built-in function lstat>): [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/path_to_dask_temporary_directory/scheduler-mwho36kr'
```

I'm running the script via Slurm, so in case the error might be related to that, I'm also posting the relatively long Shell script I'm using to run the Python file.

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --job-name=job_name
#SBATCH --nodes=3
#SBATCH --ntasks=3
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=256
#SBATCH --output=/path_to_log_folder/%x.log

export DASK_TEMPORARY_DIRECTORY=/path_to_dask_temporary_directory

WORKERS=4
THREADS=64

SCHEDULER=scheduler.json
LOGS=/path_to_log_folder

SING_RUN="singularity run --nv -B/directory /path_to_sif_image/$2.sif"

srun --nodes=1 --ntasks=1 --output=$LOGS/%x.schd.log \
      $SING_RUN dask scheduler --scheduler-file $SCHEDULER &> $LOGS/log.schd.out &

srun --nodes=2 --ntasks=2 --output=$LOGS/%x.wrk.log \
      $SING_RUN dask worker --interface ib0 --scheduler-file $SCHEDULER --nworkers=$WORKERS --nthreads=$THREADS &> $LOGS/log.wrk.out &

cd /path_to_python_script &

$SING_RUN python -u $1 &> $LOGS/log.job.out
```

Comment: I see you are using Singularity. Do the Dask worker ran inside the image have access to the TEMP directory you are specifying?

Comment: Yep, we applied chmod 777 to the directory just to be sure. This error is still showing up despite that, but we have since discovered that in spite of the error the script seems to be working as intended. This error pops up when Dask is demobilizing the workers after the processing is done.